# Should One Use Pandas or Sklearn for Imputation/Normalization etc.?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to get myself more familiar with sklearn, though I am still kind of a newbie to ML. While working through a couple of tutorials I stumbled across sklearn implementations of techniques I already did using pandas. Like tools for normalization, imputation of missing values etc.

My current workflow looked like this: Loading and preprocessing data using pandas, doing normalization, imputation etc with them ,mostly in a notebook. Then I export the csv-File to a cleaned version and do my ML work in seperate python-files on this cleaned and processed dataset. Is there anything wrong with this workflow?

I'd really like to here from some people that spent more time in the field than me on which there are any advantages/disadvantages to use pandas for preprocessing or using sklearn. Maybe you already saw some roadblocks I didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if after doing imputation, normalization (and other "data cleaning / preprocessing" steps), you plan on doing some actual Machine Learning, you should use scikit-learn. The main advantage is that you can easily concatenate all your preprocessing steps, and your final Machine Learning estimator, in a single [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline) object.
This is very convenient if you want to make sure to apply on new data the same steps that you applied on training data. Your code will also be more compact and readable.
Also take a look at [Column Transformers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#column-transformer) (that can be included in a Pipeline), if you need to apply different preprocessing steps to different columns of your original data.

On the other hand, if your project does not involve Machine Learning, and you only need to preprocess and clean your data to visualize it and to calculate some statistics, you may decide to only use Pandas, so your project will have less dependencies.